# JSONSerialization crash only on fresh ios simulator

Tags: ios, swift3, simulator

```
let params = ["first":"string", "second":["any":""]] as [String: Any]
let serverUrl = URL(string: "https://example.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/prod")!
var request = URLRequest(url:serverUrl)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("secret", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Api-Key")
do {
    request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
} catch _ as NSError {
    return
}
```

This crashes on a fresh ios simulator on line 8, but when tried again works. I have tested different hypotheses but can't seem to find out why.

I've tested:

1. isValidJsonObject()
2. the mixed nested dictionary
3. the empty string
4. Dictionary'<'String, Any> vs [String:Any]

The crash error message is 'Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_i386_GPFLT)'. I've checked to see if there were any mistakes with threading but my grand central dispatch seems to be outputting the correct data in the correct order.

Any clues?

Is this problem only limited to the simulator or will it also appear in a physical ipad?

Edit: Further googling has suggested it is a problem with the empty string somehow contributing to returning nil. I can force the empty string into a null value, however I am still troubled by the fact that the above code ONLY crashes in a fresh simulator, but works flawlessly after.

Comment: what you want to pass in your second parameter ?

Comment: Hi there, Ive edited to fix the mistake and also added in the rest of the request for completion. However my testing has shown that it is the params dict that crashes the JSONSerialization function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe you need to encode your urlRequest with your params. Firstly, you must cast your dictionary to `[String : Any]` and then edit your encode. For example, you can do this:

```
let params : [String : Any] = ["first":"string", "second":["any:""]]
do {
        request = try URLEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with: params)
    } catch _ as NSError {
        return
    }
```

Now, if your request has POST or PUT method you must to specify your settings by http body and headers:

```
urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, 
                                                 options: [.prettyPrinted])
```

Comment: Hi there, you may be onto something. I will first create an empty dictionary var before putting in the variables to test this theory.

Comment: the test is inconclusive, the crash still happens regardless of initializing a empty dictionary beforehand.